# Blazor Server Path Issues

Tags: c#, web, server, blazor, .net-6.0

I hope someone can help I'm still pretty new to Blazor and I've been struggling with this problem all day.

I had a Blazor Server app that ran fine on my local machine and also fine on my deployment server (Ubuntu/with Apache proxy).  It ran fine for months until I needed to move it from the root of the server to a subfolder e.g. https://myserver/myapp.  That's when my nightmare began.  Even though all the content paths are relative for css, images etc they were all trying to load from the root / of the website after I moved it.

There's several ways I have found for setting the path of the app.

```
app.UsePathBase("/myapp")
app.UseStaticFiles("/myapp")
```

Setting these seem to be completely ignored when deployed on the server for some reason so I had to look for other options.  I then found that you can simply set the path in the  tag in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<base href="/myapp/" />
```

This worked great... all the content loaded as intended and I thought it was fixed until I realised none of the dynamic js elements was working.

I tracked that down to a incorrect path in the script tag "/_framework/blazor.server.js" so I corrected the script tag to be "_framework/blazor.server.js".

Now its trying to load the script from https://myserver/myapp/_framework/blazor.server.js -  the problem is that path does not exist!  Yet somehow it works fine on my local dev environment.

I've tried many things... even copying the _framework folder from my local environment to wwwroot manually - which resulted in some strange errors and did not seem like a good idea.

I've also tried using ~/ as the base href which works locally but breaks on the server where it's just trying to serve everything from the root folder again.

I don't understand why things are working very differently in the development environment and the published server build.  I also can't seem to change where that _framework folder is located and so can't load the necessary script files.

Is it something you do with the app.MapBlazorHub() command?

Comment: Please try this: <base href="~/myapp" />. I know you use the `~`, But that might be because of an extra trailing `/`

Comment: If I don't provide the trailing / everything is attempting to load from the root directory.  It works with ~/myapp/ however it doesn't solve the missing blazor script issue I am having.

Comment: See this repo of mine that shows how to run multiple Blazor sites from the same root which might help you. - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Medusa

Comment: So according to @MrCakaShaunCurtis 's repo, you should change the script path as follows: `/myapp/_framework/blazor.server.js`

Comment: And add this line to startup: `builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });`

Comment: @AlirezaK I had tried /myapp/_framework/blazor.server.js I had it correctly trying to load the script from that path - the problem was the script was literally not there.  It's not a static file in the project wwwroot directory on Blazor Server apps, I think it's served by the app at runtime and it was not being found at all (404).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below to your `_layout` file configures the signalR hub to use an absolute path instead of a relative path:

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withUrl("/_blazor");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, you can use your absolute path for it.

Comment: I tried this, but I get both a 404 for blazor.server.js not found and also Uncaught ReferenceError: Blazor is not defined.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I worked around this by placing my app on it's own subdomain myapp.myserver.com.  It doesn't really solve the original problem but Blazor Server apps just seem to work with much less hassle when they are in the located in the root path.